# yii2 How to count days between dates exclude weekends and holiday

Tags: php, yii2

Okay first of all, before some of you might put this question into a duplicate question. i have been go through many questions related to my question. But it seems like those questions cannot solve my problem. i want to find days between 2 dates excluding weekend and holidays. the questions that i have been go through declare the variable of `$holiday` in array and initialize the value in that array.

Below is my code in `LeaveapplicationController.php`for finding days exclude weekends

```
$date1 = $model->startDate;
        $date2 = $model->endDate;

        $date1 = strtotime($date1);
        $date2 = strtotime($date2);


        //Initialized public holiday
        $holidays = array("2020-01-21", "2020-01-22", "2020-01-23");

        $days = ($date2 - $date1)/86400 + 1;

        $fullWeek = floor($days/7);
        $remainDay = fmod($days,7);

        $firstDay = date("N", $date1);
        $lastDay = date("N", $date2);

        if($firstDay <= $lastDay){
            if($firstDay <= 6 && 6 <= $lastDay) $remainDay--;
            if($firstDay <= 7 && 7 <= $lastDay) $remainDay--;
        }
        else 
        {
            if($firstDay == 7){
                $remainDay--;

                if($lastDay == 6){
                    $remainDay--;
                }
            }
            else{
                $remainDay -= 2;
            }
        }
        $workDay = $fullWeek * 5;
        if($remainDay > 0)
        {
            $workDay += $remainDay;
        }
        foreach($holidays as $holiday){
            $timeStamp = strtotime($holiday);
            if($date1 <= $timeStamp && $timeStamp <= $date2 && date("N", $timeStamp) != 6 && date("N", $timeStamp) != 7)
            $workDay--;
        }
        $model->no_of_days=$workDay;
        $model->save();
```

So, i have tried with holiday that has been initialized with some values. In my case, i want to replace that `$holiday=array()` with data from another table of database. Is there any best way to do it?

Comment: Find holidays between `startDate` and `endDate` First. You need to go through every date between two dates to exclude dates from `holiday and weekend` then count days.

Comment: @InsaneSkull for example i have go through all dates and have put them into public holiday table in db. how can i retrieve those data to put them into `LeaveapplicationController.php`?

Comment: @InsaneSkull i have edit my question to make my question clearer

Comment: I Understood your whole scenario. I will answer your question in few hours.

Comment: be cautious of this: `$days = ($date2 - $date1)/86400 + 1;` a day has not always 86400 seconds: depending on what locale your server has, there is daylight saving, making one day of the year 25 hours long, and one day only 23 hours

Comment: @SteBächler Noted about that. Thank you sir

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thank you for spending your time on my question sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DateTime`

```
$start = new \DateTime($model->startDate); //2020-01-01
$end = new \DateTime($model->endDate); //2020-01-31
$endDate = $end->format('Y-m-d');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$end->add($interval);
$period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    $allDates[] = [
        'date' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
        'dayNo' => $date->format('N'),
    ];
}

//Initialized public holiday
 $holidays = HolidayModelName::find()
    ->select('date')
    ->where(['between', 'date', $start->format('Y-m-d'), $endDate])
    ->indexBy('date')
    ->column();

$workDay = 0;

foreach ($allDates as $value) {
    $isWeekOff = $value['dayNo'] == 6 || $value['dayNo'] == 7;

    if (!$isWeekOff && !isset($holidays[$value['date']])) {
        $workDay++;
    }
}

// Result : 20 Work Days
```

Comment: based on your answer, you initialized the date in the `$start` and `$end`. but my `$date1` and `$date2` are from database. how can i retrieved the date from the database?

Comment: @Aech `$start = new \DateTime($model->startDate);` Edited the answer

Comment: why did i get error at `$end->add($interval);` this is the error `Call to undefined function app\controllers\add()`

Comment: @Aech Because you don't have datetime object for `$end`  like  `$end = new \DateTime($model->endDate);`

Comment: i already initialized it like this `$date1 = new \DateTime($model->startDate);
               $date2 = new \DateTime($model->endDate);
               $interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
               $date2 = add($interval);
               $period = new \DatePeriod($date1, $interval, $date2);`

Comment: @Aech `$date2 = add($interval);` should be `$date2->add($interval);`

Comment: ohh im sorry, i didnt notice that. now it works! so how can i replace that initialized `$holidays` with the data from the database?

Comment: @Aech Holiday table have `start date` and `end date` or only `date`.

Comment: `date` only which is refer to the public holiday dates. i already add the picture on the answer section below

Comment: @Aech Updated my answer. Look for new variable `$endDate` in beginning.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you very much! its working right now. I really really appreciate yr helps and the time you've spent to help me.

Comment: @Aech No problem. Glad to help you.